# Need to burn FAT32 CD from Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, windows, cd-burning, fat32

Please tell me how to burn a FAT32 CD under Snow Leopard (10.6.8).  I have tried multiple approaches, including creating a FAT32 .dmg properly sized for the disc, and burning from the Finder or from Disk Utility.  The thread at [How to burn Windows compatible CD on Mac OS X Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63531/how-to-burn-windows-compatible-cd-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion) did not help me.

The image correctly shows up as type FAT32 in Disk Utility, but the resulting disc invariably shows up as type Mac OS Extended.  I am trying to do this because some Windows users are reporting not seeing anything on the disc I sent them.  It was my understanding that the Mac automatically creates CDs that can be read by both OS X and Windows.

Comment: How does the thread not help you?

Comment: Mark, I tried what the thread says to do but I still end up with type Mac OS Extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a FAT32 CD. Windows does not use that format for CD/DVDs.

Normally, when burning a bunch of files, both Mac and Windows use `ISO 9660 (Joliet)` for CDs and `Universal Disk Format (UDF)` for DVD media. Format is automatically chosen once media is detected.

Also there is no need to make an image first. You just

- select the files in Finder
- right click on the selected files
- select Burn.

Comment: It appears that Disk Utility reports CDs as format Mac OS Extended no matter how or where they were burned.  I find that rather confusing.

Comment: It doesn't on my 10.6.8 - It clearly says `Format: ISO 9960`. Something is seriously messed up on your system!